# How to resolve constructor overload ambiguity

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ambiguous

I am making a Fractions class which I want to be able to work with all Numeric types. It is school related, so I am limited to VCSE 2010, keep that in mind. My constructor works with Double values as parametres, so almost any number would work with it... except Decimal, because there is no implicit conversion. When I code in an overload that takes Decimal parametres, though, it throws a constructor overload ambiguity error with Integer types, because both overloads require precisely one conversion. Is there a way to work around this? For example, make one overload priority over the other, or somehow make an implicit conversion override private to the class? I had an idea of making a private Struct which basically serves as a Double struct clone, but has implicit conversions to and from Decimal, but I'd really prefer a more eficcient method. My biggest priority is having to do no work to resolve the ambiguity outside of the Class, even if working inside the Class exclusively is more work. Here's my code:

```
public struct Fractions
{
    public double Num, Den;
    public Fractions(double n, double d)
    {
        try { double x = 1 / d; this.Num = n; this.Den = d; } catch { throw; }
    }// This constructor first tries to divide by the denominator input, to make sure it's not 0 
    public Fractions(decimal n, decimal d)
    {
        try { double x = 1 / d; this.Num = n; this.Den = d; } catch { throw; }
    }// Same comment as above
    /* Methods, operators, &c... */
}
...
public static void Main(...)
{
    Fractions f = new Fractions(1, 1) /* Default fraction for the Main method, and so the 
                                         ambiguity arrises... */
}
```

Comment: The workaround is simply to add an overload that takes `int` as parameter. Note that it's perfectly OK to have a single constructor that takes `double` as parameter, and leave the burden of casting to the caller. That's what most APIs do

Comment: Why do you even want multiple constructors in the first place? You have repeated code here which is a code smell and not necessary.

Comment: Multiple constructors is not exactly what I want, what I want is a constructor/constructors that work with any and all Numeric types. I guess I can just make a constructor with object parametres and work from there, but thank you for your input! :)

Comment: I'd love to know what the point of `catch { throw; }` is. Why catch if you're just going to throw, just let the exception bubble up without a `try/catch`

Comment: @Charlieface I do not know why exactly I wrote that in, that part of the code is old, I believe I intended to expand on it. I've commented it out for now and thank you for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify as what numeric type your numbers should be treated:

```
   Fractions f = new Fractions(1d, 1d); // will call the double arg constructor
   Fractions f2 = new Fractions(1m, 1m);// will call the decimal arg constructor
```

Of course you can define a specific constructor that takes two integers as arguments (as suggested by @Kevin Gosse) but this way you will end up with duplicated logic:

```
public Fractions(int n, int d) 
{
    // fields assignment
}
```

Comment: Well there's no need for duplicate logic. The int constructor can call the double constructor: `public Fractions(int n, int d) : this((double)n, (double)d)`

Comment: Thank you for your input! But such specifications, or any workarounds outside of the main class is precisely what I'm trying to avoid - I want my class to be infinitely flexible and convenient.

Comment: @TheMarty27 Infinitely flexible is a misnomer, for example would you accept a `BigInteger`? What about a `NaN` value? There's a lot of edge cases here

Comment: @KevinGosse yes, this can be done in order to avoid duplication but if you are going to use casting why wouldn't you do it outside the constructor - `Fractions((double)n, (double)d)` ?